# Circular loop when using selection changed datagrdivew

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using a datagradview and I am  wanting to prompt the user to save the current row before moving off I have been trying to use the following event but I seem to be in a circular loop when I hit my save event.

```
private void dgStock_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        if (isDirty == true)
        {
            isSavedFromRow = true;
            btnSaveDetails_Click(sender, e);

            isDirty = false;
        }
}
```

The problem with the selection changed event is this happens once the row has changed so the user could think their saving the new row and not the current row.

I also seem to be caught in a circular loop some how has the messagebox box is getting fired numerious times I am only setting the isDirty to true if the user enters key down on my textboxes.

```
if (isDirty == true)
{
            DialogResult _result = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you wish to upate Live Product Information", "Save Changes", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            if (_result == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                updateStock();
                _trackChanges.Clear();

                isDirty = false;
            }
 }
```

This is me setting my dirty flag on key down felt this was best way to avoid the problem I seem to be having.

```
private void txtDescription_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
        isDirty = true;
        btnSaveDetails.Enabled = true;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code sample suggests that your save stuff is defined in your save button click. If you change your structure to something like this

```
private void SaveClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DoSaveStuff();
}

private void DoSaveStuff()
{
    // Do your save stuff
}
```

i.e. pull your save stuff out into a method. You can call `DoSaveStuff()` whenever you need to save, e.g.

```
private void SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Do stuff

    if (condition)
    {
        DoSaveStuff();
    }
}
```

The advantage of this approach is you're capturing the aspect of the behaviour you're interested in - the save stuff - rather than the whole button click. Furthermore, you click a button to save, your application doesn't, it simply saves in certain circumstances, e.g. when you click a button or when something changes.

As [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectionchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) says the `SelectionChangedEvent` occurs whenever the selection has changed. So, whenever this happens you could check your original selection to see if it has changed and then save if it has. Maybe doing something like this

```
private void SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool hasContentsChanged = // determine if your content has changed

    if (hasContentsChanged)
    {
        DoSaveStuff();
    }
}
```

An advantage of this approach is that you'd only have to save if it really had changed, i.e. if the original text != new text, rather than in all cases.